# Animation only works when the window is resized

Tags: flutter, dart

The problem is that the animation only works if you start resizing the window. Tried on windows, web, android. Used by `StatefulWidget` and `SlideTransition`. The class is complex enough to post this code here.

Has anyone experienced this/similar issue?

Comment: Are you calling setState to trigger a new build during transition?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it turned out worse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is when we pass new coordinates(x, y) data to `CustomPaint` we may need override method `shouldRepaint` in `CustomPainter` with value `true`:

```dart
@override
bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
```

The second problem is when we pass mutable data in widget and such widget is many. The data should be immutable.